# Does Servlet Container create ServletConfig object if there are no init-params?

Tags: java, servlets, servletconfig

I know, that when Servlet Container instantiates Servlet object, it also creates respective ServletConfig object, where it stored all init-params for that servlet (which we can later fetch via servlet by `.getServletConfig().getInitParameter(..)`

My question is what happens when we don't have any init-param in the servlet element? does the container still create ServletConfig with no init-params? *(`.getSevletConfig()` does not return null, so I'm not sure whether ServletConfig is created in runtime when invoking this method, or container still creates that object with no init-params)* or in this case, container does not create ServletConfig object? if it does, why we may need that ServletConfig object?

Comment: So you are asking whether `getSevletConfig()` will always create a new instance of `ServletConfig` if there are no init params ?

Comment: Well, if Container does not create - then yes, that is the question, and why we may need that ServletConfig object in that case.. but who knows, maybe container creates that object at context startup.

Comment: At least tomcat creates only one such object per servlet: org/apache/catalina/core/StandardWrapper.java:124 (tomcat 8.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ServletConfig`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html) does not contain only init params but also a reference to the `ServletContext` and the servlet name, so it makes sense even if no init param has been specified.

Comment: But the central purpose of it is exactly init-param.. as several books state this. So to answer the question: container still creates it on startup.. right?

Comment: Sure, on startup.